# How to save the force on a molecule in GROMACS?

Tags: computational-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, software

I am a new student of molecular dynamics. I have started using GROMACS a month ago.

I have a small box of 8192 molecules each with 3 atoms. I froze the last molecule and ran the simulation. I even converted the `.trr` file from binary to `.gro` and checked that the last molecule indeed stayed in the same place.

However, I want the `.trr` file to print the force on each molecule or each atom - in the x, y, and z-direction.
I even set the `nstfout` in the `grompp.mdp` file to a reasonable non zero number - 5000.

However, the `.trr` file - when converted to `.gro` - did not show the force. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and **how to get GROMACS to save/reveal the force in the `.trr` file?**

Comment: It may be considered off-topic as the question is about using program - more appropriate on computational science SE

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic here.  However, it may well be true that other sites may be able to answer better.

Comment: The GROMACS Users mailing list is a good place for such questions http://www.gromacs.org/Support/Mailing_Lists/GMX-Users_List

Answer (score 6):

Gro output format does not support forces, so using it as an intermediate output format defeats your purpose.

Use

```
gmx traj -f your.trr -of
```

which runs the `gmx` wrapper binary, calling the `traj` module to do trajectory processing, names your input trajectory file after `-f` and triggers the output of forces with `-of` (optionally named after `-of`, defaulting to `force.xvg`), or similarly

```
gmx dump -f your.trr
```

to dump the entire contents of the file including forces) to the terminal.

See also

```
gmx help traj
```

or

```
gmx traj -h
```

or http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/5.1/onlinehelp/gmx-traj.html

Note that I currently develop GROMACS.